# TinyMce - Copy/paste changes url of image

Tags: url, tinymce

On my site I use url rewrite mode and probably that's causing troubles...
I use my own image insertion and it works fine (I enter image abolute url and using button it is converted to html tag). Problem occurs only when, in editor, I copy (or cut) picture (which has absolute url) and then paste it again to text. Pasted version of url is relative and I don't know how to make it absolute as original, how to block url conversion?

Here is code:

```
...
convert_urls : false,
relative_urls : false,
remove_script_host : false,
document_base_url : "<TMPL_VAR NAME=DOCUMENTBASEURL>",
...
```

This combination show images and it works, but then, url is not absolute. For example, if image is located in http://localhost/site/img/id.jpg it's url will be converted to "/site/img/id.jpg". It's pretty strange kind of url and I wonder how it even works. But, as I said, I need to have an absolute image url

```
...
convert_urls : true,
relative_urls : false,
remove_script_host : true,
document_base_url : "<TMPL_VAR NAME=DOCUMENTBASEURL>",
...
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me fix this.
Thanks in advance,
Ile

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with copy paste as well. I am using the paste plugin and the settings

```
relative_urls : false,
remove_script_host : false,
paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : false
```

worked for me